# ramda js concat the value using reduce

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an array of data that will be converted into a string. I have created the function for doing the conversion. My question is what is the best way to write this function to make it more readable? I don't want to have multiple `if/else` statements.

```
const data = [
    "hello",
    {name: "Bob"},
    "and",
    {name: "Fred"},
    "How are you guys today?",
]

const isString = R.is(String)
const isObject = R.is(Object)

const getName = R.prop('name')

const toPureString = R.reduce(
    (result, value) => {
        if (isString(value)) {
            return `${result}${value} `
        }
        if (isObject(value)) {
            return `${result}${getName(value)}`
        } 
        return result
    }, "")

toPureString(data)
// hello Bob and Fred How are you guys today?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do something like this:

```js
const {compose, join, map, unless, is, prop} = R
const data = ['hello', {name: 'Bob'}, 'and', {name: 'Fred'}, 'How are you guys today?']

const transform = compose(join(' '), map(unless(is(String), prop('name'))))

console.log(transform(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

[`unless`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unless) is a simplified `if-else`, which returns the original value unless the predicate returns true, in which case it applies the transformation function first.  ([`when`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) is similar, except that it applies the transformation *when* the predicate is true.)  So this proceeds in two steps, first converting everything to a consistent format, plain strings, and then combining them.

This might read better to you, but they are entirely equivalent:

```
const transform = pipe(
  map(unless(is(String), prop('name'))),
  join(' '), 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `R.cond`:

```js
const { flip, is, unapply, join, useWith, prop, T, identity } = R

const isString = flip(is(String))
const isObject = flip(is(Object))
const spacer = unapply(join(' '))
const getName = useWith(spacer, [identity, prop('name')])

const toPureString = R.reduce(R.cond([
  [isString, spacer],
  [isObject, getName],
  [T, identity]
]), '')

const data = [
    "hello",
    {name: "Bob"},
    "and",
    {name: "Fred"},
    "How are you guys today?",
]

const result = toPureString(data)

console.log(result) // hello Bob and Fred How are you guys today?
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramda has a [`ifElse`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ifElse) function. However it becomes clumsy when you have multiple branches to your `if` statement:

```
const ifStr = R.ifElse(isString, v => `{result}{v}`, () => result);
return R.ifElse(isObject, v => `{result}{getName(v)}`, ifStr);
```

For that case, I would do it with a ternary statement in plain JavaScript:

```
const toPureString = R.reduce((result, value) => {
    const str = isObject(value) ? getName(value) : (isString(value) ? value : '')
    return `${result}${str}`
}, '')
```